# RecyclerView just scrolls 1 item

Tags: android, xml, layout

my layout is:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/pureWhite"
    tools:context=".ControllerPickerActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#00cc3d"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/controllers_picker_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/pureWhite"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_plus_30dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

my problem is that my `RecyclerView` view doesn't scroll properly. I have 20 items but it shows 9 elements on the first screen and I can just scroll 1 item and not anymore. I can just get to 10th element.

I'm new using `RecyclerView` in `CoordinatorLayout`, and none of the tutorials I saw helped me solve my problem.

can anyone show me how to solve this problem or show me an example to handle a `RecyclerView` in a `CoordinatorLayout`?

my recyclerview item:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/row_padding_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/row_padding_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/controller_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColor="@color/pureBlack"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/controller_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/pureBlack"
        android:layout_below="@id/controller_title" />
```

my Adapter:

```
public class ControllerPickerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ControllerPickerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private List<Controller> controllerList;

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title,id;
        public MyViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            title = v.findViewById(R.id.controller_title);
            id = v.findViewById(R.id.controller_id);
        }
    }

    public ControllerPickerAdapter(List<Controller> controllerList) {
        this.controllerList = controllerList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.controller_list_row, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Controller controller = controllerList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(controller.getTitle());
        holder.id.setText("" + controller.getId());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return controllerList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure your `recyclerview` item layout height is `wrap_content` not `match_parent`

Comment: @NileshRathod tnx for answer, as you can see in my layout code, it is `wrap_content`. changing that to any value didnt work

Comment: Not the height of your `RecyclerView` but the height of `RecyclerView` item layout my friend

Comment: @NileshRathod   aha, i checked that too. it was correct. and i added my item code too

Comment: Than share you adapter code and  item layout of RecyclerView

Comment: add scroll flags to your recyclerview `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"`

Comment: @KaranMer hell of a tnx bro, it fixed scrolling issue. but i got another problem that i can scroll more than all of my items to blank spaces (where i cant scroll back because it seems there is no view there). do you have any idea why?

Comment: try using `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not added scroll flags to your RecyclerView. Try adding it using below code, use scroll value that suits your requirement.

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

Comment: but if you finally found a way to make it work complete properly it would be appreciated. hope my question can help others too :)

Comment: enter always will scroll always, try only using scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Why u put RecyclerView inside AppBarLayout? is it necessary? if not, then use this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/pureWhite"
    tools:context=".ControllerPickerActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#00cc3d"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/controllers_picker_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/pureWhite" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_plus_30dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

or u can try this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/pureWhite"
    tools:context=".ControllerPickerActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#00cc3d"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/controllers_picker_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/pureWhite"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_plus_30dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: it works if i put that outside of appbar but it is necessary for me to put that inside. its weird that it scrolls but into a limited number of items.

Comment: Can u please explain, exactly why u need this? Cause inside AppBarLayout, its difficult to retain the scroll behavior of the RecyclerView.

Comment: i think i'll lose features in future. there are some tutorials i've seen putting and working with recyclerview inside there.

Comment: and about your answer, setting appbar to match_parent makes me able to scroll down but i just still see 9 elements. i mean there are blank space below number 9 element.